# byte[] formatting of Cerebrata Azure Management Studio

Tags: azure, arrays, azure-storage

I am trying to debug an issue where my data is stored in Azure Table Store as a byte[]. I am using the Cerebrata Azure Management Studio and it shows the byte[] column as:

16000000010000000E00000001010400000031343230

Does anyone know what format this is stored in? How can I convert this into a byte array? It does not look like a base 64 or UTF encoded string.

Answer (score 0):

Haha... the data is literally stored as bytes, just in hex form.

i.e. 16000000010000000E00000001010400000031343230   is really:

16 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 0E 00 00 00 01 01 04 00 00 00 31 34 32 30

:-)

So the rest is trivial... I used a quick function like this:

```
var hex = "16000000010000000E00000001010400000031343230";
byte[] bytes = new byte[hex.Length/2];
for(int i=0; i<hex.Length;i+=2)
{
    bytes[i/2] = byte.Parse(
        hex.Substring(i, 2), 
        System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
}
```